# Unable to hand errors with try/except, subprocess and bedtools

Tags: python

I am having an issue handling errors with try/except and subprocess.

```
try:
   subprocess.run("bedtools interset ...", sheel=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e)
    quit()
```

Bedtool is not able to identify one of the files and print it in the terminal

```
Error: Unable to open file
```

but this is not caught by the try/except. Python doesn't run the except part and then keeps running. I know that it is bedtools the one that is printing the error message because if I delete the `print(e.output)` nothing changes.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the bedtools process actually return a non-zero value? If not, `subprocess` will not know that an error occurred.

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am doing wrong?

[`subprocess.run` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) claims that

> If *check* is true, and the process exits with a non-zero exit code, a
> `CalledProcessError` exception will be raised. Attributes of that
> exception hold the arguments, the exit code, and stdout and stderr if
> they were captured.

default value for `check` is `False`, so you need use `check=True` if you want behavior described above, that is you should be doing

```
subprocess.run("bedtools interset ...", shell=True, check=True)
```